# How to add flags to highcharts export server when started as a module

Tags: highcharts

I configured my own export server on EC2.
I have a file with following code:

```
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server')
exporter.initPool({maxWorkers: 1});
exporter.startServer();
const app = exporter.server.app
module.exports.server = app;
```

and then I start it using pm2 library.

According to their documentation (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#breaking-changes-in-v210) I should start the server with allowCodeExecution flag set to true if I would like for export server to recognize callbacks.

My question is how I can add a flag --allowCodeExecution while starting a server like a module?
I know that I can start it using following command

```
highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1 --allowCodeExecution 1
```

but I am not sure how I can use that flag(or any other) if I am starting my server as a module.

Thank you.

Comment: But are you talking about firing by cmd or actually by a separate file as a node module that calls the export function?
Because if there is this second option, then you need to check at what point this allowFileResources is used in the code and how it goes to the forwarded options.
Because when you run normally through cmd, there is the logic that takes your arguments and processes it properly. For the node module, we need to check how to provide this argument in the code.

Comment: I started my highcharts server like this in AWS EC2 on port 80 and I invoke it via http request from my spring boot application. If that answers your question @madepiet

Comment: then how did you install the export server?

Comment: using package manager. npm in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the answer to my question but I started export server via highcharts-export-server command as I posted originally in my question and I was able to utilize that approach for my needs.
Although it would be useful to know how to add various flags as options while starting the export server as a module.